# Twitter OAuth Echo and multiple endpoints

Tags: api, rest, twitter, oauth

I am busy with a delegator (api rest service), most of the methods of this delegator are using multiple endpoints of twitter. I want to use OAuth Echo for the authorization, but as far as I know the oauth signature is generated based on one endpoint, so you can't use the same header for multiple endpoints.

So is it possible to use OAuth Echo in this situation? and if not are there other clever ways to accomplish this?